# Including C++11 header file with in C++ source file

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, mocking

I'm trying to figure out how to make use of C++11 headers in my C++ project. Specifically I'm trying to use FakeIt mocking framework (https://github.com/eranpeer/FakeIt) for unit testing my legacy application which is built with C++.

The FakeIt page says it is supported for both C++11 & C++ projects but when I build my application with the header from the library it complains about not able to resolve the C++11 symbols.

```
gtest/include/fakeit.hpp:28:25: error: unordered_set: No such file or directory
gtest/include/fakeit.hpp:29:17: error: tuple: No such file or directory
gtest/include/fakeit.hpp:32:18: error: atomic: No such file or directory
```

I'm new to C++, so would appreciate any pointers here thanks.

Comment: "C++11 header with in C++ files" what does that mean?

Comment: I have a C++ source file which I build with g++ compiler (without C++11), but I want to include a C++11 header file. I would like to know how this would work or would it even work ?

Comment: @broun _"without C++11"_ It's not possible without using the `-std=c++11` option. What did you expect?

Comment: The FakeIt Git page says it can be used with C++ projects, so im trying to decrypt it and understand how to use it for my project. Again, Im new to C++ so Im trying to make sense of how to use FakeIt.

Comment: C++11 is not a separate language, it's a version of C++. If you want to use C++11 features in your project, you have to compile it as (at least) C++11. With g++, this means passing the `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: Please write a meaningful title.

Comment: "FakeIt is written in C++11 and can be used for testing both C++11 and C++ projects." Seems like an error in their documentation. If it is packaged in a single header file, and it uses C++11, you cannot compile your project without C++11.

Comment: Hmm, this is what I was afraid of. anyway have reached out to the repo owner for clarification on this, will update once I hear back. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, got response from FakeIt, looks like the option suggested was to build the test project with C++11 and leave the production with C++. Thanks all for the help pointers..

Answer (score 3):

C++11 support is often not enabled by default. Compile your program with the `-std=c++11` argument. For example:

`g++ -std=c++11 -I/path/to/libray file.cpp`

Also, do make sure your compiler actually supports C++11, it should complain if it doesn't understand `-std=c++11`. [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) is a list of C++11 features supported by various g++ versions.